# Why does this code continuously output '2'？

Tags: python, list

```
class Node:
    child = []

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data


node1 = Node(1)
node2 = Node(2)
node1.child.append(node2)
while node1.child:
    print(node1.child[0].data)
    node1 = node1.child[0]
```

I think it will output only one '2', but in fact, it continuously output '2'. I don't know why. Can somebody help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: child is a class variable, meaning it is shared among all instances. So your node2 also gets itself as a child.

Comment: put the `child` attribute inside `__init__`

Comment: Thank you so much! so how can I solve it? I just want  each instance to maintain its own child, and the count of child is variable.